# Oracle query inner join trouble

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
select  
     s.w
```

i have this simple query setup where i can list the wisdom of a given avatar, but how do i list more than one avatar, for example the above query only list the dads wisdom, but if i remove the m.dad line, it lists the mums wisdom, but how do i list both. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use different aliases for your SuperAvatars and reference them in the `SELECT` list:

```
select  
     mum.wisdom as wisdom_mum,
     dad.wisdom as wisdom_dad
from
     megaAvatars m
     inner join superAvatars mum on mum.sAvatarsID = m.mum
     inner join superAvatars dad on dad.sAvatarsID = m.dad
where
     m.hoard = 100
```

Comment: simple and quick solution thanks. (minor error mom.sAvatarsID, i think you ment mum.sAvatarsID :)

Comment: You're right, of course - originally I had everything as mom, then I noticed you used mum, changed it and forgot one occurrence. Fixed.